# Delegate function not work in jquery 2.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-2.0

I have This code for load content in `comment-list` `div` for pagination using jQuery `delegate`:

**JS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#comment-list .pagination a').delegate('click', function() {
        $('#comment-list').fadeOut('slow');

        $('#comment-list').load(this.href);

        $('#comment-list').fadeIn('slow');

        return false;
    });         

    $('#comment-list').load('index.php?route=simple_blog/article/comment&simple_blog_article_id=<?php echo $simple_blog_article_id; ?>');

</script>
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="comment-list"> 
  <div class="pagination">
    <div class="links">
     <b>1</b> 
       <a href="http://localhost/oc/index.php?route=simple_blog/article/comment&amp;simple_blog_article_id=5&amp;page=2">2</a> 
       <a href="http://localhost/oc/index.php?route=simple_blog/article/comment&amp;simple_blog_article_id=5&amp;page=3">3</a>
       <a href="http://localhost/oc/index.php?route=simple_blog/article/comment&amp;simple_blog_article_id=5&amp;page=2">&gt;</a>
       <a href="http://localhost/oc/index.php?route=simple_blog/article/comment&amp;simple_blog_article_id=5&amp;page=3">&gt;|</a> </div><div class="results">Showing 1 to 5 of 11 (3 Pages)
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But In action My code not work and not load content in `div`. after click in pagination link, I see open new window and load my content. I test my code in `jQuery 2.1.1` Version and I think `delegate` not work in `jQuery 2.1.1`.

How do fix my problem?

Comment: Change `$('#comment-list .pagination a').delegate('click', function() {` to `$('#comment-list').find('.pagination').delegate(' a', 'click', function() {`, since `delegate` has been discouraged, you should use `.on`

Comment: You should use `.on()`. However, your syntax is not correct, use `$('#comment-list .pagination').delegate('a', 'click', function() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.
>
> For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method.

Use event delegation **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead :

```
$('body').on('click', '#comment-list .pagination a', function() {
    ....
});
```

Hope this helps.